# Simple Example of Sending J2EE-MIB Stats to an SNMP Manager

Tags: java, snmp, mib, snmp4j

I'm looking for a simple java example that actively sends SNMP stats to an SNMP Manager using the [J2EE-MIB](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tools/management/downloads/J2EE-MIB) or the [JVM-MANAGEMENT-MIB](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/JVM-MANAGEMENT-MIB.mib). My intent is to use [SNMP4j](http://www.snmp4j.org/) against CA Spectrum, but any Java API against any generic SNMP manager is fine. I'm comfortable sending simple traps, but I'm unsure on how to proceed using a more complex MIB and how to specify dynamic groups. For example, the J2EE-MIB defines JDBC Pool metrics, but the individual metrics must somehow be associated to a pool name.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SNMP4J-AgentJMX has a built-in support for the JVM-MANAGEMENT-MIB.

I would not recommend (discourage from) using traps to send the whole contents of a MIB specification. Instead you should use the trap-directed-polling approach (can be found in FAQ of comp.protocols.snmp).